# R Plot : Size of the legend box with legend(), difference with RStudio

Tags: r

I usually use R Studio when I need to write some code in R. But as soon as I want to make plots with a legend, I switch to the R Gui because the legend box from RStudio is different and unpleasant for me.

Let me explain with an example:

```
sigma <- (1:7000)/10000

ratioMSY <- 1 - 5.26 * sigma^2
plot(sigma, ratioMSY, type="l", ylab="MSY(sigma^2)/MSY(0)", ylim=c(0,1), 
 lty=2, cex.lab=1.5, bty="n", cex.axis=1.5, lwd=3)

par(new=T)
ratioMSY <- 1 - 2.78 * sigma^2
plot(sigma, ratioMSY, type="l", ylab="MSY(sigma^2)/MSY(0)", ylim=c(0,1), lty=1, 
 cex.lab=1.5, bty="n", cex.axis=1.5, lwd=3)

par(new=T)
ratioMSY <- 1 - 1.96 * sigma^2
plot(sigma, ratioMSY, type="l", ylab="MSY(sigma^2)/MSY(0)", ylim=c(0,1), lty=3, 
 cex.lab=1.5, bty="n", cex.axis=1.5, lwd=3)

legend(0,0.4,c("r = 0.1","r = 0.2","r = 0.3"), lty=c(2,1,3), cex=1.5)
```

Now I do it with RStudio and with RGui.

*With RStudio:*

[image]

*With RGui:*

[image]

See the difference ? In fact, the legend with RStudio has far two big spaces between each lines. I can solve it by using `y.intersp = 0.5` but it doesn't seem *natural* because I would do it each time I make plots, and the box stays big (only the spaces between the lines are reduced, not the spaces above and below the lines).
I have tried almost all options of the `legend` function, without success. The `cex` option doesn't solve the problem.

I didn't find anything on Google, and this is the first time I ask a question on StackOverflow, so I hope it will be ok.

Comment: It's worth noting that I can similarly "break" your nice legend by plotting to a different window size in RGui.

Comment: have you tried saving it out as a png or svg vs display to the visible graphics device? That's def the way to go if you plan on using the chart somewhere and you'll get predictable output every time (provided you use the same parameters).

Comment: By saving as a png with `png("filename.png")`, it works well ! (the result is terrible if I use `dev.copy(png, "filename.png"))`
Thank you !